# auto fill text field depending on selected item in grails

Tags: jquery, grails

I have a text field Price in my OrderItem domain.

The price should auto-change/auto-fill depending on the Product selected

[image]

How do I go about this using Jquery? So far I have done is

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadProduct(id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "${resource(dir:'product/get')}/" + id,
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    var div = $('#posthere')[0];
                    if (result.error)
                        alert(result.error.message);
                    else {
                        $('#price')[0].value = result.product.price;
                        compute();
                    }
                    //$('#dialog').dialog('open');
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    var div = $('#posthere')[0];
                    div.innerHTML = textStatus + " " + errorThrown;
                    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                }
            });
        }
        function compute(){
            var price = parseFloat($('#price')[0].value);
            var quantity = parseInt($('#quantity')[0].value);
            $('#totalAmount')[0].value = price * quantity
        }
        $(function(){   // on load
            var price = $('#price');
            price.on('change', function() {
                compute();
            });
            $('#quantity').on('change', function() {
                compute();
            });
            $('#product').on('change', function() {
                loadProduct($('#product')[0].value);
            });
            if (price[0].value == '')
                loadProduct($('#price')[0].value);
            else
                compute();
        });
    </script>
```

I'm not sure if I had made an error above, please help me fix? The compute function is working fine but whenever I select a product the price field does not change

OrderItem Domain:

```
int orderNumber
int quantity = 1
Customer customers
Product product
BigDecimal  price
BigDecimal  totalAmount = 0

static constraints = {
    orderNumber min:1, blank: false
    quantity            min: 1, blank: false
    price       min: 1.00, scale: 2, maxSize: 19 , blank: false
    customers()
    product()
    totalAmount min:0.00, blank: false
}

static mapping = {
    totalAmount formula: 'QUANTITY * PRICE'
}
String toString() {
    return orderNumber
}
```

Product domain:

```
 static hasMany = [orderitem: OrderItem]
String productCode
String productName
int quantityInStock
BigDecimal price
static constraints = {
    productCode blank: false, unique: true
    productName blank: false
    quantityInStock blank: false, min: 1
    price blank: false, min: 0.01
}
public String toString(){
    return productName
}
```

am i missing something here? Any help will be greatly appreciated. thank you

```
       OST http://localhost:9001/static/product/get/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)
send @ jquery-2.1.3.js?compile=false:8625
ajax @ jquery-2.1.3.js?compile=false:8161
loadProduct @ create:43
(anonymous function) @ create:94
i @ jquery-2.2.0.min.js?compile=false:2
fireWith @ jquery-2.2.0.min.js?compile=false:2
ready @ jquery-2.2.0.min.js?compile=false:2
J @ jquery-2.2.0.min.js?compile=false:2
    create:72 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined
error @ create:72
fire @ jquery-2.1.3.js?compile=false:3094
fireWith @ jquery-2.1.3.js?compile=false:3206
done @ jquery-2.1.3.js?compile=false:8261
(anonymous function) @ jquery-2.1.3.js?compile=false:8600
```

The above code is for the outputted console error in google developer tools

Comment: OST http://localhost:9001/static/product/get/ 405 (Method Not Allowed) you have a space in that try url: "${resource(dir:'product/get')}/" + id.trim()  to see if that resolves it. this is getting an image i presume ?

Comment: @vahid the error is gone, that is supposed to get the values within the product chosen. price still does not show automatically upon selection of an item

Comment: Added note, when I change to "${resouce(dir:'product/get"0}/"+id.trim(), the compute function doesn't work anymore

Comment: The very first point why do you have a folder in resources called get ? call that something else secondly that looks all wrong "${resource(dir:'product/get'}/"+id.trim()  Now try doing this console.log('about to get >'+"${resource(dir:'product/get'}/"+id.trim()+"<");  Not that extra 0 with brackets was wrong - the resources had an r missing as well.

Answer (score 0):

This bit looks wrong you have not put enough brackets around it

```
 if (result.error)
                        alert(result.error.message);
                    else {
                        $('#price')[0].value = result.product.price;
                        compute();
                    }


 if (result.error) {
                        alert(result.error.message);
                    } else {
                          console.log('---we have '+result.product.price);
                        $('#price')[0].value = result.product.price;
                        compute();
                    }
```

Your developer console on your browser(Chrome) is your best friend  - that bit should have thrown some form of java script error

I have added a console.log which should show if you even get to that segment with the updated code

Comment: Hello again @vahid. I will edit the question to contain the error in console

Comment: div.innerHTML = textStatus + " " + errorThrown;  that's your only innerHtml comment it out change it to console.log